# Is possible to prevent a site using my code?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, software

I was told even when we cannot patent the code, there is a copyright or intellectual property on it. But what can we do with that? is that protecting from someone else using the code?

If yes, what are the legal tools to act on some site using that code?

Because I can also think in different scenarios:

1. Javascript code, without modification: if some site is copying the code is easy to check, code is visible
2. Javascript code, modified (minified, obfuscated, or some minor changes to the code)
3. Backend code, without modification: in this case we don't have access to it, how can we know if they are using our code then?

Comment: You can sue people who violate your copyright, if they do that.  How to identify copied code isn't really a legal question, though.

Comment: Why is not legal? I mean is not a legal problem to define "when" some code is considered a copy or not? and is not a legal problem to define how to check if someone is violating copyright on code that is not visible in the browser (backend)?

Comment: No, "how do I find evidence that something has been copied?" is not a legal question. What you do with evidence of copyright violation is.

Comment: @Nij why not? the law can give you some tools to get the evidence right? a search warrant for example

Comment: Getting a search warrant is not something you can do as a civilian, even mentioning it demonstrates you have misconceptions about what is part of the legal process and what is not. Once you have identified copied code, how to use that evidence on court is a legal question; the actual identification is technical and is not at all part of the legal process.

Comment: @Nij So if I suspect someone is using my code in the backend the only way to get the evidence is hacking their system (which is in fact ilegal)?

Comment: How you get it is largely irrelevant to whether you can prove it's violating copyright.

Comment: @Nij can you give an example of how someone could prove that? I mean, imagine some hacker sends me their files, then I need to go to the justice and present that as a proof? saying "this was sent to me by an anonymous hacker"? and then what happen if the company says: "that's not our code so we are not copying anything"? how can be resolved a thing like that without a legal tool similar to a "virtual search warrant"?

Comment: You get your code. You get their code. You get an expert to compare them and say they were copied. You get a lawyer. They do the rest

Comment: @Nij that's the problem, how can I get their code? and even if I can obtain it (with will be something ilegal) then how can I prove the code I'm presenting as their code is actually their code? what if they just say: "that's not my code"?

Comment: How you do that is up to you. How you do it legally is up to your lawyer.

Comment: @Nij ok but that's my question, you say is the work of my lawyer, and I don't know how he could do that, can you give me an example of how you could prove some company is copying code? (I'm assuming you are a lawyer)

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do with copyright protection is sue a person who infringes on that right. As a pre-lawyer step, you could file a DMCA notice with the service provider alleging infringement, which should get the stuff taken down, but the process is a bit formalistic and still boils down to filing an infringement lawsuit.

Then you have to provide evidence that it is most likely that your code was copied. It naturally depends on the nature of the code, but degree of similarity can be quantified, and a paid expert could testify that is is extremely unlikely that the similarity is by accident or is natural (e.g. the centigrade-to-farenheit conversion formula). This also holds for modifications. If you have a good reason to claim that they have infringed code in an invisible location, you can get a subpoena requiring them to provide you with a copy so that you can do your forensic analysis on that code.

Comment: Do you know about the price and times for for a demand like this? I mean not exactly, but is this something that only big companies can afford because usually takes too long and are too expensive?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is difficult and expensive to prove that your code is used somewhere else as pointed out in the answer from user6726. Sometimes it becomes obvious like [here](https://www.theverge.com/tldr/2016/5/4/11593084/dont-get-busted-copying-code-from-stack-overflow). It is especially difficult if your code is slightly modified or someone runs an obfuscator over it.

A simple trick you can do is the following: Modify some constants (e.g. pi or sqrt(2)) slightly which has no impact on your calculations but will probably not be changed by someone copying your code:

```
final double PI = 3.14159264359;
```

Looks like pi but is wrong by 0.0000003 % and will most likely not be modified, and it usually still there after obfuscation.

At least you could now approach the copyright violator with a good proof.